# Area map into a bootstrap tab not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-plugins, tabs, responsive, area

I have a bootstrap tabs that is working well.
I have an area map that is working well if it is not inserted into a tab.
I use the Responsive Image Maps jQuery Plugin from Matt Stow, also works fine.

**The symptom:**
Then I put the area map into one of the tabs, a not active by default.
Then I click on the tab to make it shown. So the img is well shown.
But the area map does not working. I can't see the clickable rect.
But if I manually resize my navigator, then the area map works.

The page: https://boutique.bilp.fr/71-les-pieds-de-poteaux.html
Select tab "Guide de choix", the white rectangles should be clickable. THey are not until I manually resize the window.

**The cause:**
The responsible is the Responsive Image Maps jQuery Plugin. In its code, it makes a call to the jquery .width() method to obtain the width of the img where the map should works. And because the parent (tab) is hidden, the returned width is wrong. And it uses it to resize the map... with bad values. The map is then so small that it seems to not work.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to modify the Responsive Image Maps jQuery Plugin by making ancestors visible before calling width().

Original code:

```
/*
* rwdImageMaps jQuery plugin v1.6
*
* Allows image maps to be used in a responsive design by     recalculating the area coordinates to match the actual image size on load and window.resize
*
* Copyright (c) 2016 Matt Stow
* https://github.com/stowball/jQuery-rwdImageMaps
* http://mattstow.com
* Licensed under the MIT license
*/
;(function($) {
$.fn.rwdImageMaps = function() {
    var $img = this;

    var rwdImageMap = function() {
        $img.each(function() {
            if (typeof($(this).attr('usemap')) == 'undefined')
                return;

            var that = this,
                $that = $(that);

            // Since WebKit doesn't know the height until after the image has loaded, perform everything in an onload copy
            $('<img />').on('load', function() {
                var attrW = 'width',
                    attrH = 'height',
                    w = $that.attr(attrW),
                    h = $that.attr(attrH);

                if (!w || !h) {
                    var temp = new Image();
                    temp.src = $that.attr('src');
                    if (!w)
                        w = temp.width;
                    if (!h)
                        h = temp.height;
                }

                var wPercent = $that.width()/100,
                    hPercent = $that.height()/100,
                    map = $that.attr('usemap').replace('#', ''),
                    c = 'coords';

                $('map[name="' + map + '"]').find('area').each(function() {
                    var $this = $(this);
                    if (!$this.data(c))
                        $this.data(c, $this.attr(c));

                    var coords = $this.data(c).split(','),
                        coordsPercent = new Array(coords.length);

                    for (var i = 0; i < coordsPercent.length; ++i) {
                        if (i % 2 === 0)
                            coordsPercent[i] = parseInt(((coords[i]/w)*100)*wPercent);
                        else
                            coordsPercent[i] = parseInt(((coords[i]/h)*100)*hPercent);
                    }
                    $this.attr(c, coordsPercent.toString());
                });
            }).attr('src', $that.attr('src'));
        });
    };
    $(window).resize(rwdImageMap).trigger('resize');

    return this;
};
})(jQuery);
```

The modified code:

```
/*
* rwdImageMaps jQuery plugin v1.6
*
* Allows image maps to be used in a responsive design by recalculating the area coordinates to match the actual image size on load and window.resize
*
* Copyright (c) 2016 Matt Stow
* https://github.com/stowball/jQuery-rwdImageMaps
* http://mattstow.com
* Licensed under the MIT license
*/
;(function($) {
$.fn.rwdImageMaps = function() {
    var $img = this;

    var rwdImageMap = function() {

        $img.each(function() {
            if (typeof($(this).attr('usemap')) == 'undefined')
                return;

            var that = this,
                $that = $(that);

                // Since WebKit doesn't know the height until after the image has loaded, perform everything in an onload copy
            $('<img />').on('load', function() {

                // Modif BC : make ancestors visible so .width() can return the right value
                //************************************************
                var hidden_ancestors = [];
                $that.parents().each(function() {
                    if ($(this).css('display') == 'none')
                    {

                $(this).show();
                        hidden_ancestors.push($(this));
                    };
                });
                // END Modif BC

                var attrW = 'width',
                    attrH = 'height',
                    w = $that.attr(attrW),
                    h = $that.attr(attrH);

                if (!w || !h) {
                    var temp = new Image();
                    temp.src = $that.attr('src');
                    if (!w)
                        w = temp.width;
                    if (!h)
                        h = temp.height;
                }

                var wPercent = $that.width()/100,
                    hPercent = $that.height()/100,
                    map = $that.attr('usemap').replace('#', ''),
                    c = 'coords';

                $('map[name="' + map + '"]').find('area').each(function() {
                    var $this = $(this);
                    if (!$this.data(c))
                        $this.data(c, $this.attr(c));

                    var coords = $this.data(c).split(','),
                        coordsPercent = new Array(coords.length);

                    for (var i = 0; i < coordsPercent.length; ++i) {
                        if (i % 2 === 0)
                            coordsPercent[i] = parseInt(((coords[i]/w)*100)*wPercent);
                        else
                            coordsPercent[i] = parseInt(((coords[i]/h)*100)*hPercent);
                    }
                    $this.attr(c, coordsPercent.toString());
                });


                // Modif BC : Restore invisibility on ancestors
                //*********************************************
                jQuery.each(hidden_ancestors, function(index, value)
                {
                    $(value).css({display: ''});
                });
                // END Modif BC

            }).attr('src', $that.attr('src'));
        });
    };
    $(window).resize(rwdImageMap).trigger('resize');

    return this;
};
})(jQuery);
```

I will propose this improvment to Matt Stow, the author

Comment: Works like charm! Thanks a lot Bruno!